# Change between styles according to active

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to switch between `list view` and `grid view` using the code below (not working cause I have no idea how to switch between `active` and `not active`):

```js
// List view
<button className={styles.viewBtn `${view === 'list' ? 'active': ''}`} onClick={() => setView('list')} type="button" title="List View">
     // <svg>
</button>

// Grid view
<button className={styles.viewBtn `${view === 'grid' ? 'active': ''}`} onClick={() => setView('grid')} type="button" title="Grid View">
    // <svg>
</button>
```

So to style the buttons I do `import styles from ./styles.less` and here's my css for the buttons:

```css
.viewBtn {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin-left: 8px;
    transition: .2s;
    
    &.active {
      background-color:  rgba(195, 207, 244, 0.2);
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    &:not(.active):hover {
      background-color:  rgba(195, 207, 244, 0.1);
      color: #fff;
    }
}
```

How do I switch between `.active` and `:not(.active)` for the `style` of the buttons? And would `.active` work in `React`?

Answer (score 0):

your css would be like this

```
   .viewBtn {
      ... your btn css
    }
    
    /* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
    .active, .viewBtn :hover {
      background-color:  rgba(195, 207, 244, 0.1);
      color: #fff;
    }
```

in jsx use like this

```
className={`viewBtn ${view === 'list'? 'active': ''}`}
```

Comment: What about `not active class`? Also, in `jsx` I'm doing style by `import styles from ./styles.less` so I would need to do like `styles.viewBtn` to style the button.